# free online internal knowledge base

Tags: project-management, knowledge-base, resource-management

I would like to ask for a recommendation of an online platform that could be used as an internal knowledge base for specific topics

Ex:

Today I've worked in project X, so I add to the base the project X, material associated with it and references to these materials.

Tomorrow, somebody can perform a search in this base and find (if related) my project or materials related to it.

If possible, I would like to such a platform to be easy insert and search for data.

Thanks.

Comment: Should it be personal (only you can read/write), or company-only, or totally public, editable by anyone on the Internet?

Comment: You want it to be usable online, without installing anything, right?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul,  should be company only. If possible without installing anything.

Comment: Do you need to upload files (PDF, LibreOffice files, etc) and must their content be findable via search?

Comment: yes, possible code files, PDF' and some links to articles

Comment: What is your budget?

Comment: as low as possible

Answer (score 1):

What about [Gitlab](https://about.gitlab.com/) . It is not only a code repository but also has a wiki, to-do-lists and an option to organise to-do-lists as Kanban boards. I think a better search feature can be installed with add-ons or third-party plugins for Gitlab.

Comment: I don't think Gitlab can find text inside PDFs.

Answer (score 1):

I use Mediawiki, because it's got great support, many people know it already, it's simple.  It's easy to throw whatever you have in there, and easy to retrieve if you're the least bit organized about categorizing the content.  Comes with an easy docker container too.

Comment: I guess you mean Mediawiki and not Wikimedia. Please note that the asker wants on online solution, without installing anything... Are there many companies offering hosted Mediawiki servers?

Comment: There are quite a few actually.. https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Hosting_services